# nginx return corrupted data from memcached

Tags: nginx, memcached

On my web site i've made data caching with memcached. It stores fully generated html pages. Next step was to get this data from memcached by nginx and send back to user w\o starting apache process.
First i tried to get data from cache by php backend and it worked. But when i try make this with nginx - i see hardly corrupted data. smth like [image]

i'm asking for help with this problem.

p.s. here the part of nginx config if it can help

```
location / {
    #add_header    Content-Type  "text/html";
    set $cachable 1;

    if ($request_method = POST){
        set $cachable 0;
        break;
    }
    if ($http_cookie ~ "beauty_logged") {
        set $cachable 0;
        break;
    }

    if ($cachable = 1) {
        set             $memcached_key   'nginx_$host$uri';
        memcached_pass  127.0.0.1:11211;
    }

    default_type    text/html;
    error_page      404 502 504 405 = @php;
    #proxy_pass http://front_cluster;
}

location @php {
    proxy_pass http://front_cluster;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem was in specific memcached behavior. even if you turn off data compression, memcached do it if your data exceeds limit in 20k symbols. the cure is - (in my case) on caching backend do smth like `$this->_memcache->setCompressThreshold(20000, 1);`

p.s. i am using Zend_Cache_Backend_Memcached as a parent class of my backend. so the string above must be at `__contstruct()`

Answer (score 5):

Nginx does not process the content stored in Memcached, it just gets it and returns to the browser as is.

The real cause is the Memcached client library your application uses. Most of the libraries compress large values (usually when value size exceeds some threshold), so you must configure it not to do so, or set [`memcached_gzip_flag`](http://nginx.org/r/memcached_gzip_flag) (first appeared in Nginx "unstable" 1.3.6) with [gunzip module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gunzip_module.html) enabled.

Comment: do you mean php5-memcache lib or php library, in my case - Zend_Cache?

Comment: actually, in my application i am using Zend Framework and by default Zend_Cache_Backend_Memcached "compression" is false

Comment: Is there a way to get nginx to decompress zlib compressed data?

Answer (score 1):

The response you've posted seems like gzipped one. My first guess is that `Apache` is returning response with `transfer-encoding=gzip` which is stored into `memcached`, but then when popped and returned from `nginx` through `memcached`, the `transfer-encoding` header is omitted, thus the browser receives wrong response. You can easily test if this is the case with disabling gzip compression in `Apache`.

If this is the case, you should look for a solution to preserve the `transfer-encoding` header... maybe to define different rules - for non-gzipped and gzipped content, and to return always the header in the latter case. But look at this : http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpSRCacheModule. It seems like it handles such cases.

Comment: bad for me, but this is not gzipped data (

Comment: Could be a `deflate` data too... Did you try with disabling the compression in Apache?

Comment: @Tisho if only I'd looked at your previous comment... it would have saved me about 2 hours of searching. My case was `deflate`. I had tried gzip, which didn't work, but I never knew there was a difference between `gzip` and `deflate` (which is apparently `zlib`) :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

so, problem was in Memcached CompressTreshold.
when data exceeds 20k symbols, memcached turns on compression, even if conression = false.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the PHP Memcached library, bear in mind that it can only store its compressed data with [`zlib`](http://php.net/manual/fa/memcache.setcompressthreshold.php) encoding. Nginx cannot expand zlib, even with the [`memcached_gzip_flag`](http://nginx.org/r/memcached_gzip_flag) as Alexander suggests above. So, in this situation you probably should not compress data in Memcached unless you feel comfortable compressing *everything* and passing it directly to the browser with `add_header Content-Encoding deflate`.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue but I finally discovered that the memcached client was using the PHP [`Memcached`](https://www.php.net/manual/book.memcached.php) extension to save the data while we was using the PHP [`Memcache`](https://www.php.net/manual/book.memcache.php) extension to read it from memcached server.

After changing to use `Memcache` on both, issue was solved!

You may be able to fix compression issue by using `Memcache` PHP extension to save data.